# smart-operator.el not autoloading ... what gives?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to use smart-operator.el in emacs. I've put the following into my init.el file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/dotemacs_git/smart-operator/")
(require 'smart-operator)
(smart-operator-mode 1)
```

That doesn't seem to turn on smart-operator-mode automatically ... I still have to do

```
M-x smart-operator-mode
```

to get it working. What am I doing wrong? This setup [here](http://hide1713.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/setup-perfect-python-environment-in-emacs/) uses smart-operator-mode within a python-mode-hook; I don't see why making the function call conditional on python-mode would matter, though...

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you provide shows folks using

```
(smart-operator-mode-on)
```

Also, they're adding that call in a hook, like so:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
              (smart-operator-mode-on)))
```

Which will turn it on for all buffers using `python-mode`.  You'll need that since it appears that `smart-operator-mode` is not a [global minor mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Defining-Minor-Modes.html).

Comment: That did it. Didn't know about global minor modes ... thanks for pointing that out.